# Show the next image in bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show ONLY the next image and hide the previous image. Basically, I want the main image to cover 80% of the screen and the next image to cover 20% of the screen.

This code I have currently covers roughly 25% for the previous image, 50% for the current image, 25% for the next image. How do I go about this?

HTML:

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
                    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://aszx.altervista.org/aatest/img/carousel/carousel-001.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://aszx.altervista.org/aatest/img/carousel/carousel-002.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://aszx.altervista.org/aatest/img/carousel/carousel-003.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 10000
        })
        $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            if (next.next().length > 0) {
                next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            } else {
                $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .carousel {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .carousel-inner {
        width: 150%;
        left: -25%;
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        width: 25%;
    }
</style>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/q37fqy0h/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.carousel-inner{width:200%;left:5%;}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Ramachandra/q37fqy0h/8/)

Comment: There's a lot of white space to the left. Isn't there a better method than use width at 200%?

Comment: increase width to 270 and left  3 now it look better than before

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-inner {
                width: 300%;
                left: -25%;
            }
```